# Error: firebase code = 9999 Too many requests

Tags: ios, api, firebase, nest-api

Im working on an ios home automation app that uses Nest API and Firebase. I started getting this error after changing up the FirebaseManager subscription init method by basically commenting out dispatch_once block (I wanted to see if I could run it more than once):

```
+ (FirebaseManager *)sharedManager
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static FirebaseManager *instance;

    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        instance = [[FirebaseManager alloc] init];
    });

    return instance;
}
```

Now, even when I revert the code, Im still getting the error below when trying to make calls to the api. Any ideas as to how I can fix my app?

[Firebase] runTransactionBlock: at /devices/thermostats/zbb45BqLd3zfONS5MJ8j3-ybQnsbt5zx failed: blocked
2015-01-07 15:19:45.157 Home Automation[7370:1886751] Error: Error Domain=com.firebase Code=9999 "Too many requests" UserInfo=0x17026fa00 {NSLocalizedDescription=Too many requests}

Comment: Typically when you get rate limit errors on a web service, it may take some time for it to recover (or better: for it to start trusting you again). After a few hours, you may want to try again.

Comment: looks like its time for a break

Comment: Any changes to the behavior after (what seems to me like a reasonable) cooldown period?

Answer (score 2):

In order to protect the HVAC units and the battery life of the thermostat, Nest restricts the number of calls to the API.  Please see the following for a description of the rate limits.

https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/data-rate-limits