# Nest Thermostat Blocked error 9999

Tags: ios, firebase

I have an iOS app that uses a Nest Thermostat. Specifically, I want to set the Away/Home status, and then set a target temperature on it.

It works at first, but after some calls to the Nest API, i receive this error:

```
Error: Error Domain=com.firebase Code=9999 "{"error":"blocked","type":"https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/error-messages#blocked","message":"blocked","instance":"cb7307d1-4fdc-4caf-9f80-f9ad57764dd8"}" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription={"error":"blocked","type":"https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/error-messages#blocked","message":"blocked","instance":"cb7307d1-4fdc-4caf-9f80-f9ad57764dd8"}}
```

This happens both the simulator and the actual device.

I am based on the sample code provided in the Developers Nest website. It uses the Firebase API to connect to the NEST. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815002/firebase-error-code-9999-blocked) post with the same problem whilst authenticating, but I have this problem while trying to awake it. It takes around 20 minutes to be available again.

I also tried to call [Firebase goOffline] when I don't need to connect to it, and [Firebase goOnline] when I do, but it seems useless.

Do you know how it should be handled, and how to unblock the nest?

Comment: Did you go to the URL provided by the error: https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/error-messages#blocked ? It seems caused by too many calls: You'll get this message if you exceed rate limits. There are links in the doc explaining it.

Comment: Yes, I already checked that. It says I'm making too many requests with the same authToken. It is limited, but there are some places that say that I need to close the Firebase connection to ensure it is not blocking. Also, in the documentation says there is a huge limit set in the simulator, so it shouldn't be blocking there, but it blocks as well.